# Microsoft Bot Framework, calling an external custom built API send time out

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, botframework, azure-bot-service

I developed a simple REST API in NodeJS in order to access my local SQL DB(2014), the npm package used was "mssql", I tested with postman, and with the bot emulator locally in my laptop, nevertheless when I deployed the solution to Azure, a Timeout error is being received:

Node REST API:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();

var dbconfig ={
     user:  "sa",
        password: "password",
        server: "myServer",
        database: "Reports",
        port: 1433,
        options:{
            encrypt: false
        }
}

var server = app.listen(8200, function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

});
```

Bot Code:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var restify = require('restify');
var Request = require("request");

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId:"apid",
    appPassword:"pass"
});
var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);

var dialog = new builder.IntentDialog();
dialog.matches(/^soporte/i, [
    function (session, args, next) {
        if (session.message.text.toLowerCase() == 'soporte') {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Cual es el Ticket?');
        } else {
            var query = session.message.text.substring(8);
            next({ response: query });
        }
    },
    function (session, result, next) {
        // var resultado  = Consulta();
        var card = new builder.ThumbnailCard(session);

        card.title('Soporte');

        // card.images([builder.CardImage.create(session, profile.avatar_url)]);

        card.subtitle('Soporte en linea');
        var text = '';
        var cardTxt='';

        Request.get("http://ipaddress/customers", (error, res, body) => {
            if(error) {
                return console.dir(error);
            }
            console.log(body);
            text = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(text);
            text = text.recordset[0]
            for(var myKey in text) {
                 cardTxt = cardTxt + myKey+": "+text[myKey]+" ";
            }
            console.log(cardTxt);
            card.text(cardTxt);

        });

            var message = new builder.Message(session).attachments([card]);
            session.send(message);

    }
]);

bot.dialog('/', dialog);

var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

error: JUST when deployed:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.212:8200
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.212',
port: 8200 }
```

Comment: Are you able to try this with an HTTPS endpoint instead of HTTP and see if that makes a difference? `"http://ipaddress/customers"`

Comment: Did you test with postman from your local machine (where the DB is hosted) or from another computer? Could you try it with one that is on an entirely different network? It seems like you might need to set up your DB endpoints so they are visible on the internet.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your response, I'm gonna configure https to test the API with a secure connection (I haven't done that test). And Mark, yes, the DB is at the customer offices, and Im testing with POSTMAN  in my local machine, as well as with the Microsoft bot emulator and everythings work fine. The error appears only when I deploy my bot to Azure.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? As I am having the same issue, I  am assuming its a DNS issue from Azures side of things...@EduardoNava